# PHP sybase_connect from nagios script

Tags: php, sybase, nagios

Has anyone had problems connecting to a sybase database using sybase_connect in PHP running as a nagios plugin?

My script runs perfectly under the same nagios user on the command line but if I run it via nagios it can never connect to the database, sybase_connect always returns a false connector and sybase_get_last_message is empty.
I've checked the environment settings and even though I'm doing, putenv the only thing I can see is the SYBASE variable may not be set

```
putenv ("SYBPLATFORM=linux");
putenv ("LC_ALL=default");
putenv ("DSQUERY=SYBASE");
putenv ("SYBASE=/usr/local/freetds");
putenv ("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/freetds/lib");
putenv ('PATH=/usr/local/freetds/bin');  // With this on or off makes no difference

$connector = sybase_connect ( "HOST-IN-FREETDS", "USER", "PASSWORD" );
if ($connector === false) {
         // Always falls into here if run via nagios, works if run as the same user from the command line
}
```

I've compared the settings by running:

```
$return = `set`;
trigger_error ($return, E_USER_NOTICE);
```

And checked the php error log, I've also pushed phpinfo to a file and done a diff when running it manually and via nagios.

Environment - Ubuntu LTS 14.04, Nagios Core 4.0

Any ideas anyone?  Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. putenv is likely overwriting your current values.  2. Could you fetch and post the error you get when you try to connect?

Comment: I want putenv to overwrite the environment variables they problem is it is not. However, I ran it through strace and I can see PHP is looking for the freetds.conf at script startup, so I'm wondering if you can redefine the location of the freetds.conf at runtime. The error is just it can't find the conf, if I symbolically link the freetds.conf to the default location it works, I just don't really want to do this

Comment: I think you would have to re-build freetds to change that directory.  There is an option --sysconfdir=DIR, that sets it.